# Android: InstanceID deleteToken Scope

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was implementing Google Cloud Messaging in an app. Firstly I get the token using InstanceID, the next step is to register the device in my server and I get an HttpResponse. Depending of this response, I would like to delete the token and unregister the device in my server. This is the code:

```
// [START register_for_gcm]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            final String token = instanceID.getToken(manager.getSenderID(),GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // [END get_token]
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
            final Context context = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    HttpResponse response = manager.registerDevice(context, App.getInstance().getAppId(), token, null, null);
                    // At this point all attempts to register with the app server failed, so we need to unregister the device from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                    // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an unregistered callback upon completion, but GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                    if (String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).equals(200)==false){
                        instanceID.deleteToken(token, scope);
                        manager.unregister(context);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }
            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
```

I was looking in the Android Developers [Google Developers InstanceID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID#deleteToken%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and I found `deleteToken(String authorizedEntity, String scope)`. The authorizedEntity is the token obtained in getToken() method, but I don't know what the scope is.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Based on the [GCM Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#obtaining_a_registration_token), `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE` is the scope you can use for the `InstanceID` related method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scope is "GCM" or the constant

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE
```

The authorizedEntity is your project number. Here is the [reference link](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#generate_a_token)